# How to break a column to fix a php table

Tags: php, php-7.4

I had a little problem, i cannot break the table because I'm looking for a 16 columns in these table to create a unicode table...
The aim is to find where i must break the line of the column as like as there:

```
<?php 

$columnas = 16;
$filas = 16;
$word= 0;
$contador = 0;

print "<table border=\"1\">\n";
print "<caption>ASCII</caption>\n";
print "<tbody>\n";
print "<tr>\n";

for ($j = 1; $j <= $columnas; $j++){
    if ($j%2 == 1){
        print "<th>Codigo</th>\n";
    }elseif ($j%2 == 0){
         print "<th>Valor</th>\n";
    }
}
print "</tr>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $filas; $i++){

    for($i = 1; $i <= 50000; $i++,$contador){
        $unicodeChar = "&#{$i}";
        $contador--;
        print "<td>" .$i. "</td>\n";
        print "<td>".$unicodeChar."</td> \n";
    }   
    print "</tr>\n";
}   

print "</tbody>\n";
print "</table>\n";
 
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTSLQ.png)

Comment: "i cannot break the table" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that i can't divide these columns that replied @RiggsFolly who told me that is the better way, i'm so sorry if i wrote worst, is not my better english, but i' try to improve it in next questions... thank you for the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the modulus in the first loop, so use it again in the second

```
print "</tr>";

print "<tr>";
for($i = 1; $i <= 50000; $i++){
    $unicodeChar = "&#{$i}";
    $contador--;
    print "<td>$i</td><td>$unicodeChar</td>\n";

    if ( $i % $columnas/2 ) == 0 ) {
        print "</tr><tr>\n";
    }
}   
print "</tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for this help, i have been fixed!!

here is the code that i fixed, with your idea :)

´´´´

```
<?php 

$columnas = 16;
$filas = 16;
$word= 0;
$contador = 0;

print "<table border=\"1\">\n";
print "<caption>ASCII</caption>\n";
print "<tbody>\n";
print "<tr>\n";

for ($j = 1; $j <= $columnas; $j++){
    if ($j%2 == 1){
        print "<th>Codigo</th>\n";
    }elseif ($j%2 == 0){
         print "<th>Valor</th>\n";
    }
}
    print "</tr>";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $filas; $i++){
        print "<tr>";       
        
        for($i = 1; $i <= 50000; $i++,$contador){
            $unicodeChar = "&#{$i}";
            $contador--;
                   print "<td>" .$i. "</td>\n";
            print "<td>".$unicodeChar."</td> \n";

            if (($i % 8 ) == 0 ){
                print "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }   
        print "</tr>\n";
    }
    

print "</tbody>\n";
print "</table>\n";
 
 ?>
```

´´´´

[image: Table with these columns that fixed by this code php]

Answer (score 1):

Like [Riggsfolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) said but maybe divide the columns number by 2 before the modulo, because there are 2 TDs / iteration:

```
if ( $i % ($columnas/2) ) == 0 ) {
    print "</tr><tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's true, this code help me about it to solve this problem, Thanks for your help too